# Is it possible to boot a LiveCD of Ubuntu via PXE using HTTP (not NFS)?

Tags: live-cd, nfs, pxe

I've found a lot of blogs explaining how to boot the installer via PXE. And I've achieved it. But now I would like to boot a LiveCD. I've seen many blogs explaining how to do this using a (DHCP+TFTP+)NFS server, but my infrastructure only has a (DHCP+)HTTP server (the latter is used to store the pxelinux.0,kernel+initrd files and the isos mount points, too).
Are there some kernel parameters "equivalent" in HTTP to NFS's netboot=nfs nfsroot=serverIp:/mount/point ...???
Thanks!!

Answer (score -3):

yes, ubuntu iso 
     for test on windows i am use tftp32 and freenfs and vmware
          c:\tftpd32\ubuntu\ (unziped iso)
       path tftp32 c:\tftpd32\
       path nfs c:\tftp32\

```
LABEL Ubuntu linux Install
KERNEL ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz 
APPEND root=/dev/nfs boot=casper only-ubiquity netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/ubuntu ip=192.168.0.5:192.168.0.1:192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:linux::none file=preseed/ubuntu.seed initrd=ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash locale=ru_RU --

LABEL Ubuntu linux Live Boot
KERNEL ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz 
APPEND root=/dev/nfs boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/ubuntu ip=192.168.0.5:192.168.0.1:192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:linux::none file=preseed/ubuntu.seed initrd=ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash locale=ru_RU --
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was if it could be possible doing the same thing using HTTP instead of NFS.