# Ubuntu boot ISO image with PXE, using just tftp, dhcp and apache but NOT NFS

Tags: iso, dhcp, pxe, tftp, memtest

This question has been asked before, without a proper answer:
[Is it possible to boot a LiveCD of Ubuntu via PXE using HTTP (not NFS)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549775/is-it-possible-to-boot-a-livecd-of-ubuntu-via-pxe-using-http-not-nfs)

It seems that there used to be a trick with *memdisk* too ([Thin Client Lubuntu over PXE Server with DHCP and TFTP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359141/thin-client-lubuntu-over-pxe-server-with-dhcp-and-tftp)), but it doesn't seem to be working anymore with the newer Ubuntu versions.

So, does anybody know how to PXE boot an *Ubuntu (desktop) ISO file (with the live session option) without an NFS?
Again, using just:

- tftp
- dhcp (i.e. isc-dhcp-server)
- apache (optional)

Comment: I'm the writer of that answer you mention using `memdisk`, I would ask you which Ubuntu image exactly you have tested already for both setups (HTTP & memdisk) : is it  Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.2 64bit?

Comment: I think it was 16.10 (64bit). If I remember right, the memdisk trick worked somehow, but the ISO could not be fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is unfortunately *no*.
You can search down information on editing the LiveCD image to make it load in such a fashion but it is a large undertaking.

Dated but representative approach: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveCDNetboot

The closest you can get to such an experience without editing the image is an install boot which you can do directly from Canonical's internet resources such as the following (note: I use `ipxe`, and this is the listing of a linux.php type file compatible with same).

```
#!ipxe

echo Starting Ubuntu x64 installer

# Figure out if client is 64-bit capable
cpuid --ext 29 && set archl amd64 || set archl i386

:setBase
set base-url http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-${archl}/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/${archl}

kernel ${base-url}/linux
initrd ${base-url}/initrd.gz
imgargs linux 

boot
```

Note: I vaguely remember reading that you can loop mount an iso LiveCD image for the dhcp / tftp handoff to accomplish this, however, if I recall this limited you to a single pxe boot image which is why I didn't explore it further. Perhaps that's a 2nd lead to search down.

Add'l reference using Clonezilla:
https://serverfault.com/questions/277470/clonezilla-pxe-boot-without-nfs